# Execute Applescript from c++ program

Tags: c++, macos, applescript

I want to execute a `Applescript` command that checks if some process is crashed and then restarts that app. I've already have the script but now i need to call it from my `c++` code.

The script is:

```
tell application "Activity Monitor" to run  --We need to run Activity Monitor
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Activity Monitor"
    tell radio button 1 of radio group 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 to click --Using the CPU View 
    tell outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 -- working with the list 
        set notResponding to rows whose value of first static text contains "Not Responding" -- Looking for Not responding process
        repeat with aProcess in notResponding
            set pid to value of text field 5 of aProcess  -- For each non responding process retrieve the PID 
            if pid is not "" then do shell script ("kill -9 " & pid) -- KILL the PID. 
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call "osascript" which is a command line tool to execute apple script. Use the built-in C "system" command to execute it. This may sound like a platform dependant hack, well it is! Wrapping the code into a designated class should be the way.

By the way: Is listening for some process activity using AppleScript a good way? You probably might be able to read process information using built-in unix features. Think about it

Comment: Well, i dont know if its a good way or not, but it was the only way i've found. If it was possible to do it using c++, it was perfect!

Comment: What you basically do is read the activity monitor using apple script, I think that your process could also be seen in the unix process monitor (ps). It is a command line tool that basically does what activity monitor does. You could 'grep' for the right process and use the data to determine a lockup!

Comment: so, what i need to do is make a string with the script and call it using `system`?

Comment: yes try executing osascript from a Terminal to see what your command line parameters look like.